# How to retrieve a particular element from a list in java?

Tags: java

I am loading a list with some values for instance config key and config value.

I need to retrieve values for each config key from the list and then add those values into another list.

The problem is that my TO object returns these values one at a time because I am looping through the list and `dcRaterName` gets overridden every time the code loops through and the second list will have only one value but not all.

I want to add all the values into my second list.

```
    List getDCRaterName= dasWebHandler.getDCRaterName(dasRequestTO);
    Iterator itr = getDCRaterName.iterator();
    
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        DasConfigTO dasConfigTO = (DasConfigTO) itr.next();
        String dcRaterName = dasConfigTO.getConfigValue();
        List<String> raterList = new ArrayList<>();
        raterList.add(dcRaterName);
        dasRequestTO.setSelectedRatersDes(raterList);
    }
```

Comment: May be you should clear your question by giving an example. Do you need all `dasConfigTO.getConfigValue()` value in a list ?

Comment: getConfigValue returns one value suppose "Hello". This is added in raterList. When the code goes for second iteration this value is being overridden by suppsoe "Word" and my list will add world. I want to add both values Hello, world in my list.

Comment: Then just declare `List<String> raterList` outside of the loop, after loop you will get the list with all value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move creation of the `raterList` *before* the loop and set it inside `dasRequestTO` *after* the loop:

```
    List<DasConfigTO> getDCRaterNames = dasWebHandler.getDCRaterName(dasRequestTO);
    List<String> raterList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (DasConfigTO dasConfigTO : getDCRaterNames) {
        raterList.add(dasConfigTO.getConfigValue());
    }

    dasRequestTO.setSelectedRatersDes(raterList);
```